# Will Java's garbage collector interrupt a thread?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Something is interrupting threads in my application.  It appears to happen when the JVM  is close to running out of heap space. I can configure additional heap for the JVM but I'm curious if the garbage collector is interrupting threads in an attempt to reclaim memory. Does anyone know?  I am using the 64 bit Java 1.6.0_16 on RedHat ES 5.2.

Thanks,

John

Comment: Define "interrupting", please. Do you mean that the thread pauses or do you get an `InterruptedException`?

Comment: In this case, the thread gets an InterruptedException.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interrupt as in throw `InterruptedException`? No, that shouldn't happen. It may need to pause the thread itself, but that's not the same thing. If the VM runs out of memory completely, it should throw `OutOfMemoryError` instead...

Answer (score 2):

Unless OutOfMemory happens, Threads will not be interrupted if garbage collection happens. They may go in wait state for sometime.

Answer (score -1):

You may be receiving so-called [spurious interrupts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28long%29). They may happen at any time but a low-memory / high-load situation may be making them more likely. However, this will depend on JVM implementation details, it's not a rule and the correlation with garbage collection (if there actually is any) is incidental and not by design.

Comment: That's entirely the opposite -- a thread is woken up *without* an InterruptedException, and without the wait condition being satisfied.

Comment: @HotLicks In one of the comments, the original author states that "In this case, the thread gets an InterruptedException.". So his situation does fit the spurious interrupt scenario.

Comment: @Michał I appreciate that you continue to research solutions for this. But the documentation you linked talks about a "spurious wakeup," not an interrupt. In my case, the interrupts were not the garbage collector, it was another thread trying to clean up after getting an OutOfMemoryError. I am pretty sure the original accepted answer was correct.

Comment: @MichałKosmulski -- As John said, the referenced article says nothing about "spurious interrupts", but rather talks about "spurious wakeups", where the wait condition is not satisfied but the `wait` operation still returns.

Comment: @HotLicks Looks like you're right and I mixed up two things. The spurious wakeup does indeed cause wait() to simply return, not throw InterruptedException. Shame on me.